# Is there a reason that "NPM Run Start" cannot find application and cannot start Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

familiar with some git and basics of programming. Learning js from a pluralsight course

I start by cloning a web-dev-starter repo into a directory:

git clone https://github.com/pluralsight/web-dev-starter.git

I do npm install

This code uses lite-server to print "Hello World" at localhost:3000

Now when I clone repo, the Script.js file is empty

So maybe that's where the problem lies. if it is, then shame on the dev for not having anything in there.

I've tried running npm install --save-dev lite-server to make sure node modules contain this

however, when I run "NPM Run Start" I see *How do you want to open this file*:
[image]

and then if I choose visual studio to open file

it opens
C:\windows\system32\npm   (a file with no extension)

Empty file:
[image]

What do I do here?

Comment: This sounds like a question for https://github.com/pluralsight/web-dev-starter/issues, not here? Remember that SO is for _after_ you've exhausted the obvious places to ask, not the first place to ask: the world benefits much more for an issue with an open source library being solved and documented _by_ that open source library.

Comment: The script.js file is intended for the frontend scripting (it's linked in the index.html file), and has nothing to do with your problem. Make sure node and npm is correctly installed on your machine.

Comment: There's something wrong with your Node installation. What happens when you run `node -v` and `npm -v` in a command prompt?